# LISP conditional programming

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a program which is very simple but though I can't figure it out please help
suppose that we have 10 circles each one has X,Y,Z,r
the program will take these variables(x,y,z,r)and find out which pair of circles can make a cylinder ( in other words which circles have same x,y,r(but not same z))
what kind of command should I use? "cond   if   if....else   if"

---

this is the very first code:

```
(setq a 10)
(setq b 10)
(setq c 11)
(setq d 12)
(cond ((= a b) (cond ( (= b c) (print 'a=b=c)  )  )
(> a b) (print 'a>b)
(< a b) (print 'a<b))
)
```

I am trying to use a COND as an action in another COND, so I could search through the numbers if they are the same but seems lisp does not accept it like C...

Comment: downvoted. No effort shown to solve the problem.

Comment: Basicly, if you have single if-then or if-then-else situation, you using if, otherwise cond may be your choise.

Comment: Please show us your code so far

Comment: sorry, I am very new to this site and lisp also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, of course, nest `cond`s as deeply as you wish:

```
(defun funny-compare (a b c)
  (cond ((= a b)
         (cond ((= a c) 'all-equal)
               (t 'only-two-equal)))
        ((< a b) 'less)
        ((> a b) 'greater)))
```

Here are some examples:

```
CL-USER> (funny-compare 1 1 1)
;;=> ALL-EQUAL
CL-USER> (funny-compare 1 1 2)
;;=> ONLY-TWO-EQUAL
CL-USER> (funny-compare 1 2 2)
;;=> LESS
CL-USER> (funny-compare 2 1 2)
;;=> GREATER
```

You just need to take care of placing the respective clauses into the correct `cond`. Automatic indenting (as well as matching parentheses and some other visual aid) makes this very trivial. Taking the code you gave above and letting emacs format it gives me:

```
(cond ((= a b) (cond ( (= b c) (print 'a=b=c)  )  )
       (> a b) (print 'a>b)
       (< a b) (print 'a<b))
      )
```

Looking closely, you can see that all s-expressions, beginning with `(= a b)` up to `(< a b)` and `(print 'a<b)` are in **the same** group of parentheses: the one which delimits a case of the outer `cond`. Therefore, all of these expressions are part of the first case, and as such you only have a single case.

What you want is this:

```
(cond ((= a b)
       (cond ((= b c)
              (print 'a=b=c))))
      (> a b) (print 'a>b)
      (< a b) (print 'a<b))
```

Look closely at the indentation!

But approaching your original problem: You should try to express the ideas you want to program in your code. You write about "circles" and such, but your code isn't expressing any of this (`a`, `b`, `c` and such are seldom good names).

Start with putting your idea of a circle into code:

```
(defun make-circle (x y z r)
  (list x y z r))
(defun circle-x (circle)
  (first circle))
(defun circle-y (circle)
  (second circle))
(defun circle-z (circle)
  (third circle))
(defun circle-radius (circle)
  (nth 3 circle))
```

Then, what you want to check are multiple independent conditions. You don't need multiple `cond`s for that, in fact, it's a lot better to be explicit with `and`:

```
(cond ((and (= (circle-x one) (circle-x other))
            (= (circle-y one) (circle-y other))
            (= (circle-radius one) (circle-radius other))
            (not (= (circle-z one) (circle-z other))))
       'planar-not-same-but-on-axis-parallel-to-z))
```

Note that this is not idiomatic lisp, because it's a lot to write that is essentially unnecessary and we need to repeat us a lot. There are a lot of tools (`defclass`, `defstruct`, accessor functions, `with-slots`, ...) available to shorten this. Thanks to the power of a list, we can even get rid of the repeated use of `=`:

```
(flet ((extract (circle)
         (list (circle-x circle)
               (circle-y circle)
               (circle-radius))))
  (when (and (every #'= (extract one) (extract other))
             (not (= (circle-z one) (circle-z other))))
    'planaer-not-same-but-on-axis-parallel-to-z))
```

Note that I also got rid of the `cond`, because a `cond` with a single case isn't exactly good code style: Use it only when you have more than twwo branches (for two branches use `if`).

I hope this helps you a bit along.

Comment: thank for your support and answers guys especially Daniel Jour
it is very helpful but I have some Questions though
The function circle-x(circle)(first circle) what does it return as a function

Comment: It returns the first element of the list that we get passed in the parameter `circle`, which is where we choose to store the x coordinate of a circle.

Comment: "(defun make-circle (x1 y1 z1 r1)
  (list x1 y1 z1 r1))
(defun circle-x (circle)
  (first (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(defun circle-y (x1 y1 z1 r1)
  (second (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(defun circle-z (x1 y1 z1 r1)
  (third (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(defun circle-radius (x1 y1 z1 r1)
  (nth 3 (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(cond ((and (= (circle-x 1 ) (circle-x 5 6 7 8))
            (= (circle-y one) (circle-y other))
            (= (circle-radius one) (circle-radius other))
            (not (= (circle-z one) (circle-z other))))
       'planar-not-same-but-on-axis-parallel-to-z))"

Comment: this was your code with a little bit change I made,but the online compiler I am using keeps erroring this: CIRCLE-X: variable X1 has no value

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun make-circle (x1 y1 z1 r1)
(list x1 y1 z1 r1))
(defun circle-x (circle)
(first (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(defun circle-y (x1 y1 z1 r1)
(second (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(defun circle-z (x1 y1 z1 r1)
(third (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(defun circle-radius (x1 y1 z1 r1)
(nth 3 (make-circle x1 y1 z1 r1)))
(cond ((and (= (circle-x 1 ) (circle-x 5 6 7 8))
        (= (circle-y one) (circle-y other))
        (= (circle-radius one) (circle-radius other))
        (not (= (circle-z one) (circle-z other))))
   'planar-not-same-but-on-axis-parallel-to-z))
```

this was your code with a little bit change I made,but the online compiler I am using keeps erroring this: CIRCLE-X: variable X1 has no value